# Can Microfrontend using Module Federation Plugin be in different repos?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack-module-federation

I am looking at developing a Microfrontend app by having a container/host app and various child apps (all are based on ReactJS, but just divided based on functionaility).
The idea is to get the benefit of independent build/deployments, etc and avoiding code conflicts between different teams working on different modules.

So my question is can Microfrontend implementation using Module Federation Plugin be in different repos ?

The examples I have seen are mostly the child apps are in the same repo, just that they are in a directory/folder of their own (e.g. child1, child2, etc)

Answer (score 2):

I have worked on Microfrontend implementation using Module Federation of Webpack. Yes, you will be able to maintain separate repos for each of your micro frontends. Will give you a summary of how we are achieving it:

Parent Repo

- The main container which will connect the rest of the micro frontends

Child Repo 1....n

- Each of them has their independent repo
- Each of them is hosted on separate domains
- We connect them in the main repo using their domain (how it's shown in the examples). As the domains will always remain static, we hard-code the endpoint in the parent repo.

The module federation repo has a lot of examples, although they are in the same folder they serve each repo independently as you want. Some examples to check out:

React 18 with routing: https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/tree/master/comprehensive-demo-react18

Shared routing: https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/tree/master/shared-routes2

Comment: I have added the examples in the answer. They are from module-federation repo. Many good examples to try out. @copenndthagen